# dust.js reference object attributes using $idx

Tags: dust.js

I'm new to dust.js. Is there a way to reference object attributes using $idx. For ex:

```
{
  "table": [
    {
         "row":
         {
               "ID": "1",
               "Domain":"Domain 1"
         }
    },
    {
         "row":
         {
              "ID": "2",
              "Domain":"Domain 2"
         }
    }]
}
```

How do I reference the ID attribute using $idx ? I might rename the columns ("ID","Domain") later-on and don't want the dustjs code to break.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible for a few reasons.

1. Most importantly, order does not matter in a JavaScript object, so there is no way of knowing what member of he object will come first. The ordering may be different in different browsers, and could change if you change the names of the keys.
2. It is not currently possible to iterate over the members of an object using Dust.

Comment: Yes, that's what I guessed would be an issue. Thanks for the reply.